# How can you select JSON object key values using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, mssql-jdbc

I have some records in my database in a column called Swatch, that are JSON to describe a colour swatch. Each record looks something like this:

```
{"colors":{"color-1":"transparent","color-2":"transparent"}}
```

Basically it's one big colour object with lots of key value pairs. I would like to manipulate this JSON, using SQL, to achieve something like this instead to allow customisable colour names.

```
{"colors":[{"name": "Red", "color":"#00000"},{"name": "Green", "color":"#00000"}]
```

(Hex codes are just for demo purposes, I know they're not legit).

How can I achieve this? It is possible using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to explain how you get from input to output.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible, but a lot depends on the data and what you are trying to achieve.
There is a set of [JSON functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) available, most of them added in SQL 2016, and a pair more should be available in SQL Server 2022.

If you want to erase the current structure and data in favor of a new one that's easy.
If you want to convert your current structure to a different one, that might be pretty hard, but it's highly data related.

Let's consider your samples as the actual data you want to convert

```json
{"colors":{"color-1":"transparent","color-2":"transparent"}}

{"colors":[{"name": "Red", "color":"#00000"},{"name": "Green", "color":"#00000"}]}
```

Here are the issues and complications I see

- how can you say what `color-1` is? what name does it have? that's human operation unless you have some ColorCode-ColorName table
- Do you have a fixed/known amount of `color-N` keys? to get the property value cleanly you will need to reference them explicitly. (but I'm sure you can find other ways... without using JSON functions tho)
- to change the structure you need to extract the data and build the new JSON string, basically a lot of string concatenation that will require quite some time to build and test

**JSON function samples**

I've played around with the JSON data and created some sample queries, I hope trying them will help you understand what it means to manipulate JSON data, and choose if SQL Server is a fitting tool for your task

```
-- key-values property
DECLARE @jdata2 as varchar(200) = '{"colors":{"color-1":"transparent","color-2":"transparent"}}'

SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(@jdata2,'$."colors"."color-1"') AS Color1
    ,JSON_VALUE(@jdata2,'$."colors"."color-2"') AS Color2
    ,JSON_VALUE(@jdata2,'$."colors"."color-3"') AS Color3
GO

-- objects and arrays
DECLARE @jdata as varchar(200) = '{"company":"Contoso","colors":[{"name": "Red", "color":"#00000"},{"name": "Green", "color":"#00000"}]}'

SELECT JSON_QUERY(@jdata,'$.colors[0]')
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jdata,'$.colors[0].name')
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jdata,'$.company')

--Update property
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'$.company', 'Northwind')
--Add property
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'$.country', 'Italy')
--Add new Object
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'$.salesman', JSON_QUERY('{"name":"Mario","surname":"Rossi"}'))
--Append new Object in an Object array
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'append $.colors', JSON_QUERY('{"name":"Yellow", "color":"#00000"}','$'))

------ About DELETING
--Delete (whole) Property works fine
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'$.colors', NULL)
-- deleting sometihng inside an array is not fine at all
-- Should delete 1 value/object from the array... but no, 'null,' is left instead
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'$.colors[1]', NULL)
-- To "delete" properly pass the whole array or object array omitting the deleted value...
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@jdata,'$.colors', JSON_QUERY('[{"name": "Green", "color":"#00000"}]'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Unfortunately looking at my data, I don't always know what the key is. It could be 'color-1', 'Colour 1', 'coleur-1' or 'Color-1'. Is there a way for me to SELECT JSON_VALUE without this? Also, I am unable to use the index because it's not part of an array.

Comment: You will have to look at string functions... (TSQL is not the best at string transformation).
I think [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can help you get all the values (by rows)... If the whole process starts getting too complex just solve it outside SQL Server.

Comment: FYI, I resolved it with lots of string parsing. It wasn't pretty but it works! :)